Problem visiting a my website in safari browser Iphone >= v.13
When accessing the site from the Safari browser on an iPhone 14, a warning message appears: "Fraudulent Website Warning." This warning does not appear in other browsers or on other devices.
The website is developed using React.js. An SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt is connected, and the server is running Nginx.
Here is the link to the site: https://powerswapmeta.io/
What could be the problem?
I've tried changing nginx settings, checking the certificate at https://www.ssllabs.com. There are errors, I fixed them, but it didn't help. Besides, it shows similar errors on other sites as well. I don't think it's the certificate.

are you using a public wifi? I just wanted to make sure there was no certificate restrictions on your web access. It's interesting how it is just happening on Safari. Have you looked into your Setting > Safari > Privacy & Security > Fraudulent Website Warning (make sure it is unchecked) That should work.
